# Can I use SQL CE 4.0 in Windows Mobile 6.5?

Tags: ado.net, windows-mobile, c#-3.0, sql-server-ce-4

The title is the question by its own!

Can I program using SQL CE 4.0 for the Windows Mobile devices? Is there any runtime that I must install to develop software on the CE 4? or it just can play using the ADO.NET API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No:

> Compact 4.0 does not have a release
>   for Windows Mobile, Windows Phone or
>   for Windows CE devices.

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx

Compact 3.5 SP2 is the latest version supported on Windows Mobile

Answer (score 0):

## Features not supported in SQL Server Compact 4.0

#### Windows Mobile, Windows Phone and Windows CE devices

SQL Server Compact 4.0 **does not have a release** for Windows Mobile, Windows Phone or for Windows CE devices.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg592946(v=sql.110).aspx